# How to create a frame of pictures with label

Tags: tables, graphics

I am trying my best to create a nice frame containing pictures that show the results of my work. It's hard to explain in words, so I give you first the idea of what I want through a scheme:

[image: Scheme]

So, the first row contains just tex and is about what the columns below contain. From the second row on, I want to place pictures (each one of the same size), with its own label (figure 1, figure 2 and so on). Everything has to be separated in a sort of a frame, like drawn in the picture above. Besides the lines of the frame itself, I would like to keep a bit of blank space between the pictures. May you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{figbox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners,halign=center,valign=center,boxsep=0pt,colback=white,equal height group=figs}

\newtcolorbox{textbox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners,halign=center,valign=top,boxsep=0pt,colback=white,equal height group=text}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4]
\begin{textbox}
And now for something completely different
\end{textbox}
\begin{textbox}
No. 3 -- the larch!
\end{textbox}
\begin{textbox}
Ministry of Silly Walks
\end{textbox}
\begin{textbox}
Theory of Brontosaurs
\end{textbox}
\begin{figbox}
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{ente}
\end{figbox}
\begin{figbox}
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{ente}
\end{figbox}
\begin{figbox}
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{ente}
\end{figbox}
\begin{figbox}
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{ente}
\end{figbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might have added an image of the Trojan Rabbit ;o)

Comment: @Bernard: Or a sketch of the Holy Hand Grenade ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer first of all! I need unfortunately more of a grid.. otherwise having a box around the images just steal some space.. I'd like more to have a tab that gives the idea of showing something related to each other instead of distinct boxes like that

Comment: @EnricoRibelli: This can all be done with the appropiate settings of `tcolorbox`,look into the `tcbraster` feature of the manual ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hmm... looks like a standard `tabular` to me. What did I miss?

Comment: @ChristophFrings: Nothing... it can be done with `tabular` of course too.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer indeed I used a tabular as you suggested and worked perfectly :)

Comment: @EnricoRibelli: Of course, but `tabular` is boring ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer true! but easier and therefore faster :P